# Jackson fails with FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES

Tags: jackson, jersey

Migrating from Jersey Client 2.22 to 2.27 with Jackson Json provider, Jackson fails on unknwown properties, even when configured properly;

```
    final JacksonJsonProvider jacksonJsonProvider = new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider()
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(jacksonJsonProvider);
```

...

```
    javax.ws.rs.core.Response r = requestBuiler.post(Entity.form(formData));
    return r.readEntity(AccessTokenResponse.class);
```

If some field not present in object, the response deserialization crashes / see stack trace.

I don't want any annotation in my object. This wasn't neceesary in previous versions.

**Stack trace**

> Caused by:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:
>   Unrecognized field "mobileNo" (class
>   ch.abraxas.oauth.egovsec.EGovUser), not marked as ignorable (20 known
>   properties: "needsApproval", "lastname", "authType",
>   "accountNonExpired", "externalId", "identifier", "accountNonLocked",
>   "otherRoles", "cariId", "credentialsNonExpired", "username",
>   "language", "organisations", "contextName", "firstname", "email",
>   "authorities", "country", "landlineNo", "enabled"])   at [Source:
>   (org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream);
>   line: 1, column: 1933] (through reference chain:
>   ch.abraxas.oauth.egovsec.client.AccessTokenResponse["user"]->ch.abraxas.oauth.egovsec.EGovUser["mobileNo"])
>      at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:62)
>      at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:834)
>   ...

**pom.xml**

```
       <javaee.version>8.0</javaee.version>
       <jersey.version>2.27</jersey.version>
       <jackson.version>2.9.4</jackson.version>

       <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey stack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

When addind missing properties, it works OK. But this should support missing attribute.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Question is how can I avoid failure on unkown properties ?

Comment: What is the stack trace like?

Comment: What do your dependencies look like?

Comment: Thanks for reading my question - I added details :)